# How to handle changes in duplicated data in NoSQL

Tags: nosql, denormalization

We're evaluating NoSQL for an upcoming project. I tend to think of things in a RDBMS way and am having trouble conceptualizing the lack of normalization.

I understand that duplicating data is not considered wrong in NoSQL. What I'm having trouble understanding is fixing changes to data to prevent anomalies.

**Explanation of Question by Example:**

> You are organizing a series of poker tournaments. You have players,
>   locations, and tournament events. As I understand it, a tournament
>   event might contain a location and a collection of players. It does
>   not need to have all the player data, but if you want to get the names
>   and home addresses of everyone going to the next tournament, that info
>   should be in the tournament collection.
>
> Someone has gotten married and moved, changing their last name and
>   address. Does the application need to update the player collection and
>   the tournament collection? Or is my model of the collections wrong? How do
>   developers "keep track" of where information is duplicated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The model that I see being used quite a bit lately is to have an immutable "master" collection of data (in your case, the list of players, the list of tournaments with the players in each tournament modeled "relationally", where the tournament record has a list of player ids), and a denormalized list (in your case, a list of tournaments with the fully-populated player data) that is only ever updated by running a periodic process over the "master" data.

This way the application only needs to update the master data, and the periodic update process will eventually rebuild the denormalized result.

Comment: When you say "immutable" do you literally mean that if *anything* changes on that master object, you're deleting it and creating a new one?

Comment: Sorry, probably the wrong use of the word there.  By immutable, I meant that the master list is not modified in the process of creating the denormalized list.

Comment: @ChrisShain Basically, you suggest maintaning 2 separate Write(master collection) and Read(denormalized collection) collections. You also mentioned about periodic updates to eventually rebuild the denormalized result. So the trade off here would be not-rendering immediate updates right ? What if we need to render near-real time updates for queries ?. And I am also worried about the impact of periodic updates and continuous read on the de-normalized collection. Also, Can you please provide some real use cases examples as you mentioned: `The model that I see being used quite a bit lately......`

Comment: @oblivion sorry- this answer is 6 years old and I would not take it as anything like gospel anymore. Depending on the platform that you are using there may be better ways to do this, for example materialized views in Cassandra.

Comment: So this is basically emulating a foreign key? Or am I missing the point here?

Answer (score 11):

One thing to do is  to have one "system of record" or master for each type of data you have. There need not be single source for all the data but each should have one.

Another measure to take is to make the data versioned (retain historical changes) so that denormalized  data can be immutable - in your example the player data for a tournament that occurred in the past is right for that time. If a player moved to a new address since then you can still get that by going to the player's "system of record" to get the current address but the tournament record reflects his/her address at the time etc.